# HTML role attribute causes content to not display

Tags: html, css

Hi there I am using the `role="main"` attribute to define the main content of my page. The problem is if I use:

```
<div role="main">
    <article class="post-preview">
        <div class="post-preview-img" style="background-image:url(img/capeEnrage.jpg);"></div>
    </article>
</div>
```

My content will not display?
If I remove the `div` tag with `role` attribute it displays without any problems.

My CSS is as follows:

```
div[role="main"] article.post-preview {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    position:relative;
}
div[role="main"] article.post-preview div.post-preview-img {
    width:inherit;
    height:inherit;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    position:absolute;
    opacity:1;
    z-index:2;
}
```

If anyone can offer any insight as to what I am doing wrong I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: have a look at my most recent edit, it might help ;)

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to set the `width` and `height` in your css of either the `article` element (example below) or the `div` having the image set as background, otherwise the background image won't show. It doesn't look like having anything to do with the `role` attribute.

```css
div[role=main] article.post-preview {
    width: 100px; /* custom size, you may change this to your liking */
    height: 100px; /* same as above */
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/93bQe/2/)**

#### EDIT #1

I have looked and looked and didn't find an explanation as to why it wouldn't work specifying percentages (`%`) for `width` and `height` for the main div. However, one thing you can do is to change the `background-size` to `contain` instead of `cover`, this way the image will fit into the container div nicely.

I also corrected the `background-repeat` bit in your code as it appeared under `background-position`:

```css
div[role="main"] article.post-preview div.post-preview-img {
    /* ... */
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    /* ... */
}
```

**[HERE IS THE UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/93bQe/3/)**

#### EDIT #2

Alternatively you could just use `img` instead; it will give you the desired result.

**[Here is the demo using the `img` element](http://jsfiddle.net/93bQe/4/)**

Comment: Thanks, it works if I set a defined width in px but if I want the width and height to be a percentage such as 100% to fill the browser window, it does not display anything?

Comment: The attribute selector is equally valid with quotes or without. It has nothing to do with the markup. There is no reason to change it (unless you really, really hate quotation marks).

Comment: @user3556920 it's better to keep away from determination the height by percentage ..

Comment: @BoltClock Have a look at the answer in the question I quoted, I didn't make it up, unless the person who answered there did ;)

Comment: @webeno: That answer doesn't say "it's the way the markup requires it". In fact, the example given in the answer implies the opposite: there's completely no relation between quotes in HTML attribute values and quotes in CSS attribute selector values. Because the two languages have completely different rules governing the validity of quoted vs unquoted values.

Comment: @BoltClock "In CSS that's an invalid unquoted attribute value" - am I missing something?

Comment: @webeno: `a[foo|bar]` is invalid because `|` is a special character in CSS, so it has to be quoted. `div[role="main"]` is valid either with or without quotes - whether or not the quotes are there doesn't change anything. I don't see how the two are related to one another.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to edit **height** in the **CSS** code from **100%** to **100px** , nothing more ...

Comment: @webeno if he would like to view all the image without cutting, he should use "contain" instead of "cover" in background-size

Comment: yep, found the same through my research, checkout my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for taking the time to look into this. Unfortunately for this to work I had to remove the role attribute.

If i use the following code it will work:

```
div[role=main] article.post-preview {
width: 100%; 
height: 100%; 
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
position: absolute;
}

div[role="main"] article.post-preview div.post-preview-img {
width:inherit;
height:inherit;
background-size:contain;
background-position:center;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
position:absolute;
opacity:1;
z-index:2;
}
```

The problem with the above code is that If I would like to have multiple articles (such as a blog) with centred background images that are 100% of the browser window in width and height I have to change the position of the article to relative and that causes nothing to display, I am not sure why but I have decided to remove the role attribute for the blog index.